# Objects are not valid as a React child If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error when I pass my detail data to modal to display. Actually the function is when user click on the post a modal appear to display Modal where detail is displayed. I am using react with redux for state management. This is my code

> Error  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {nid, title, content, noticeType, creationDate, updatedDate}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>
> noticeModal.jsx

```
const ModalDialog  = ({open ,onClose, data}) => {

        return (
            <Dialog style={{width: '100%'}} maxWidth={"sm"} onClose={() => onClose()} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title" open={open}>
                <DialogContent dividers>
                            <table style={{width: '100%'}}>
                                <tr>
                                    <TableRow title>No</TableRow>
                                    <TableRow
                                    >
                                        {data.nid}</TableRow>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <TableRow title>Type</TableRow>
                                    <TableRow>{data.noticeType}</TableRow>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <TableRow title>Title</TableRow>
                                    <TableRow>{data.title}</TableRow>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    <br/>
```

> Notice.jsx

```
<ModalDialog
              open={this.state.openDetailModal}
              onClose={this.closeDetailModal}
              data = {this.props.noticeDetail}
          />
```

Comment: Can you use `console.log(data)` in `ModalDialog` to find out what object is?

Answer (score 0):

> Error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {nid, title, content, noticeType, creationDate, updatedDate}). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This is usually caused by rendering object or array.

It can be easily reproduced.

```
<Component>{data}</Component>
```

However I don't see in your components any such occurrences. Are you sure you are checking the right component?